# Syntax error when using an assignment (of a lambda) in eval()?

Tags: python, lambda, eval

How come when I type the following

```
eval("mult = lambda x,y: (x*y)")
```

I get this as an error? What's going on?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    mult = lambda x,y: (x*y)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong? If I enter the expression as is (no `eval`) I get no error, and can use `mult` to my hearts content.

Comment: Seems to be a lot of questions trying to dynamically create variables today. I can't remember _ever_ needing to do this in real code.

Comment: i'm screwing around with a badly written Python postfix language

Comment: You may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696602/python-3-2-1-execx-y-sets-a-value-in-a-toy-example-but-not-in-the-full

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use [exec](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) instead of eval.  I don't know why you would want to do this though when you can just use `mult = lambda x,y : (x*y)`

```
>>> exec("mult = lambda x,y : (x*y)")
>>> mult
<function <lambda> at 0x1004ac1b8>
>>> mult(3,6)
18
```

Comment: what if i have a function and want to return the value of calling `mult(x, y)`?

Comment: @tekknolagi: I am not sure what you mean? calling `mult(x,y)` returns the value.

Comment: This will not work reliably. In particular, this *will not* work in Python 3.x inside a function.

Answer (score 9):

Eval does expressions, it doesn't assign.

```
>>> eval("lambda x,y: y*x")
<function <lambda> at 0xb73c779c>
>>> eval("lambda x,y: y*x")(2, 4)
8
```

You must assign the eval'd expression to a variable:

```
>>> mult = eval("lambda x,y: y*x")
>>> mult(2, 3)
6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mult = eval("lambda x,y: (x*y)")
```